# How to count input and output rows on the Spark SQL API from Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to count the number of rows that a Java process reads and writes. The process is using the SQL API dealing with Datasets of Row. Adding `.count()` at various points seems to slow it down a lot, even if I do a `.persist()` prior to those points.

I have also seen code that does a

```
.map(row -> {
  accumulator.add(1);
  return row;
}, SomeEncoder)
```

which works well enough but the deserialization and re-serialization of the whole row seems unnecessary and it isn't mentally automatic since one has to come up with the correct SomeEncoder at each point.

A third option is maybe to call a UDF0 that does the counting and then drop the dummy object it would return but I'm not sure if Spark would be allowed to optimize the whole code away if it can tell the UDF0 isn't changing the output.

Is there a good way of counting without deserializing the rows? Or alternatively, is there a method that does the equivalent of  Java's streams' `.peek()` where the returned data isn't important?

EDIT: to clarify, the job isn't *just* counting. The counting is just for record-keeping purposes. The job is doing other things. In fact, this is a pretty generic problem, I've got lots of jobs that are doing some transformations on data and saving them somewhere, I just want to keep a running record of how many rows these jobs read and wrote.

Thank you

Comment: why should `map(accumulator.add(1))` be faster than `count()`? I mean, there is no need for shuffling when using `count` without `distinct` so I doubt it's faster. I also don't understand why you think `persist` would speed up the `count` operation - I mean, it's basically waste of time if you're not reusing the dataframe in other iterations etc.

Comment: What I think I wasn't clear about is that the process is doing other things, not just counting. That is, it's grabbing some data, doing some transformation and saving that data somewhere. The counting I want to do is just incidental, for record-keeping purposes. So yes, the ```.persist()``` was an attempt at caching eg the output rows just before writing them out. And no, I wouldn't expect map to be faster than count if that is all that the job was doing, but the count lets the stream continue going while the count acts like a terminal.

Comment: Counting input and output rows a structured query deals with is what Spark SQL tracks using metrics. Have you checked SQL tab in web UI and confirm that that's what you're after? If so, accessing it after the query is finished is fairly easy.

Comment: I'd never seen that SQL tab. Thank you! Do you know if there's a way to access that programatically from Java? Would the REST API described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html be the best way?